# Change data-frame column type to string from int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` where the head looks like:

```
        DATE    YEAR  MONTH  DAY
0 2014-03-04    2014      3    4
1 2014-04-04    2014      4    4
2 2014-04-07    2014      4    7
3 2014-04-08    2014      4    8
4 2014-04-09    2014      4    9
```

The columns `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY` where taken from the `DATE` column using:

```
df['YEAR'] = df.DATE.dt.year
df['MONTH'] = df.DATE.dt.month
df['DAY'] = df.DATE.dt.day
```

Currently their types are `int64`.  I am trying to chage the type of YEAR, MONTH, DAY columns to string.  I have tried to using:

```
df['YEAR'] = df.DATE.dt.year + ""
df['MONTH'] = df.DATE.dt.month + ""
df['DAY'] = df.DATE.dt.day + ""
```

and

```
df['YEAR'].apply(str)
df['MONTH'].apply(str)
df['DAY'].apply(str)
```

I keep getting the type error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.astype(str)`

```
df['YEAR'] = df['YEAR'].astype(str)

type(df.YEAR[0])
Out[11]: str
```